# How do I move a resource to a new tf file and state without destroying and recreating?

Tags: terraform

I have a resource (aws_iam_role.derp) in my tf file which is using this state:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    region = "us-east-1"
    key = "aaaaaa"
  }
}
```

I want to move it to another state file (named "bbbbbb").

I dont want to move all the other resources in this tf file.

How do I just move this resource to another state file? I created a new tf file (in a different folder) and specified a new state:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    region = "us-east-1"
    key = "bbbbb"
  }
}
```

when i run terraform apply terraform see it as a new resource.

I want to move this resource to the new tf file without having to destroy and recreate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not sure it’s the only way, but I'll typically remove the state of the resource from current state file using "terraform state rm" followed by moving resource definition to new folder, following by import of that resource into new state file

Answer (score 2):

You can use [terraform state rm](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/rm.html) to remove the resource from state file.
You can import resource to state file with [terraform import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html)

Make sure to refactor your code accordingly as other mentioned so your resources are not being destroyed/recreated.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is,

1. you can import your resource in new tfstate file.
2. Move relevant code to new tf file.
3. remove moved code from old tf file.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.1 I believe there is a new "moved" block syntax you can use.

See https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/refactoring

> In shared modules and long-lived configurations, you may eventually outgrow your initial module structure and resource names. For example, you might decide that what was previously one child module makes more sense as two separate modules and move a subset of the existing resources to the new one.

> Terraform compares previous state with new configuration, correlating by each module or resource's unique address. Therefore by default Terraform understands moving or renaming an object as an intent to destroy the object at the old address and to create a new object at the new address.

> When you add moved blocks in your configuration to record where you've historically moved or renamed an object, Terraform treats an existing object at the old address as if it now belongs to the new address.